# Promise does not resolve through async await

Tags: javascript, promise, jasmine, async-await, jestjs

I am trying to test a javascript function, this javascript function is asynchronous and calls multiple asynchronous functions inside it, my problem is that when i call this function through testing it fails,here is my testing code:

```
it('buildTimeslots test',async ()=>{
//INPUT DATA
const extendEndDate =  moment("2018-03-20T14:50:45.636")
const staffs = ['5a3e13125cb3df25745374c0',
'5a4471929ffd6d5fa74223b3',
'5a511e532f7de3e9ef472ecb',
'5a54b25b3dfa73ce4453a5cd',
'5a5c607f4cd740279c0a3b44',
'5a38be8b4c9f0924b96d287b',
'5a39134dc8d6a869ee8f0c4a',
'5a3948589c270a0e91e3e6b5',
'5a3a2f591157385961be6834',
'5a3a788c1157385961be683a',
'5a3a78f01157385961be683b',
'5a3a79311157385961be683c',
'5a37ae947498aa1d85ef9688',
'5a3b51aa9dbc132ad0ef9ffe',
'5a9549b9e015a91e716f77fa',
'5a9a52f59695870e7a4c3a48'];

const week = "2018-03-08";
const meetingDuration = 30;
const meetingType = [ 'application review', 'any' ];

const actual = await buildTimeslots(meetingDuration, staffs, meetingType, week,extendEndDate,{ 
      fetchCurrentWeekMeetings : fetchCurrentWeekMeetings,
      fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks : fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks,
      combineAvailabilityBlocks : TimeslotsHelper.combineAvailabilityBlocks,
      buildSlotHolderForWeek : TimeslotsHelper.buildSlotHolderForWeek,
      injectStaffIfAvailable : TimeslotsHelper.injectStaffIfAvailable,
      ejectStaffIfBooked : TimeslotsHelper.ejectStaffIfBooked,
      removeUnavailableSlots : TimeslotsHelper.removeUnavailableSlots
});
console.log("in test the actual is:")
console.log(actual) 
});
```

Here is my buildTimeslots code:

```
export async function buildTimeslots(meetingDuration, staffs, meetingType, week, extendEndDate,fn) {


  const staffsIds = staffs.map(s => (s._id ? String(s._id) : String(s)));


  const availBlocks = await fn.fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks(staffsIds, week, extendEndDate, meetingType);

   //THE FOLLOWING CONSOLE.LOG DOES NOT GET EXECUTED DUE TO TIME OUT
   console.log('buildTimeslots::availBlocks', availBlocks);

}
```

fn.fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks gets called but it does not return causing the
[following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ7fe.png)

Here is fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks function:

```
    export async function fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks(
  userIds: Array<Object>,
  week: String,
  extendEndDate: moment,
  meetingType: Array<String> = ['any'],
) {
  //console.log("in fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks, the userIds are",userIds)
  console.log("AT fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks, userIds are: ",userIds)
  console.log("AT fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks, week is: ",week)
  console.log("AT fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks, extendEndDate is: ",extendEndDate)
  //mock_fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks();
  const meetingTypeArr = Array.isArray(meetingType) ? meetingType : [ meetingType ];
  // define the date boundary for the current week
  const beginDate = moment(week)
    .startOf('week')
    .startOf('day')
    .toDate();
  const endDate = extendEndDate
    ? extendEndDate.toDate()
    : moment(week)
        .endOf('week')
        .endOf('day')
        .toDate();
  // console.log('fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks: begin', beginDate, 'end', endDate);
  let query = {
    startTime: { $gte: beginDate, $lte: endDate },
    userId: { $in: userIds },
  };
  if (!_.isEmpty(meetingTypeArr) && !_.isEqual(meetingTypeArr, ['any'])) {
    query = { ...query, meetingType: { $in: meetingTypeArr } };
  }
  //console.log("in fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks",AvailabilityBlock.find(query));
  //console.log("here at fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks, found: ",AvailabilityBlock.find(query));

  return AvailabilityBlock.find(query);
}
```

Comment: So are you getting those log messages? And what does `AvailabilityBlock.find(query)` do?

Comment: If you're talking about the log function inside fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks then yes, AvailabilityBlock.find(query) finds data according to the query passed to it from the AvailabilityBlock similar to this:
https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/query/

Comment: So, have you checked whether the promise rejects? Are you handling errors anywhere?

Comment: I just added the following after reading your comment,
try{
    const availBlocks = await 
          fn.fetchCurrentWeekAvailabilityBlocks(staffsIds, week, 
          extendEndDate, meetingType);
        console.log("here after function resolve")
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log("in error, error is:",e)
  }
When i run the test it does not log the error, or the "here after function resolved"

Comment: If you do get that log message, I do not see any reason why you wouldn't get the `console.log('buildTimeslots::availBlocks', …)` as well. (Maybe apart from `availBlocks` not being in scope now when you put it inside `try`)

Comment: You should really omit those unnecessary codes, it's so difficult to read.

Comment: @RuChernChong will do